# unordered_map inside C++ class

Tags: c++, class, unordered-map

I am writing a simple logging class with C++. I want to create an unordered_map to store logging_levels, but compiling fails.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

class logging {
public:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> m_log_levels;
    m_log_levels["info"] = 2;
    m_log_levels["warning"] = 1;
    m_log_levels["error"] = 0;
private:
    int m_level = m_log_levels["info"];
public:
    void setLevel(int level) {
        m_level = level;
    }
    void warn(const char* message) {
        std::cout << message << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: And the compiler doesn't tell you why it fails? Like e.g. because you have illegal statements inside class body. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor

Comment: Ok, but why kidding and not helping? I mean, I thought StackOverflow was meant for the last one.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to be impolite, I just wrote a quick comment, because I can imagine there is already many answers to this problem and I hoped for the link to constructor documentation to be enough.

Comment: I appreciate! C ++ is a real challenge for someone like me who has used Python for many years. Thank you very much, have a nice day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put arbitrary code wherever you want in a class definition.

Initialize the hash table in a constructor i.e.

```
class logging {
public:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> m_log_levels;
private:
    int m_level;
public:
    logging() { // <<< this is a constructor...
        m_log_levels["info"] = 2;
        m_log_levels["warning"] = 1;
        m_log_levels["error"] = 0;
        m_level = m_log_levels["info"];
    }

    void setLevel(int level) {
        m_level = level;
    }
    void warn(const char* message) {
        std::cout << message << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: I really appreciate your active help. Sorry but I'm still learning and have reached the "classes" chapter (not 'constructors' yet). I know dict from Python and wanted to try adding them instead of creating too many lines of code. Thanks again!